How to resolve it when a file that doesn't exist in my remote repo keeps showing up in local?
Every time I pull from remote to my local, I see a file being deleted in git changes (with no input from me). The file does exist in local but 3 or 4 times I've checked and that file doesn't exist in the remote repo. If I push the deletion I of course get merge conflicts. Last time it happened I recloned the repo locally, but still the pesky file is there on local.
I use VS2022 connected to Azure dev ops.
Update: Yes, same file name/ext each time. It's a little tricky because I'm tracking a static web site and the file doesn't exist in the src files, but does in the compiled "dist" directory. I'd expect when I compile the site, it wouldn't include the file but it does. In this scenario, would adding the file path to gitignore cause any merge issues?

Hi Matt, does the file have a consistent name or file extension each time? If so, you can add it to your .gitignore file. If you' want to know why this file is being created, you can share the file name or contents for further analysis. Additionally, providing your specific steps, screenshots, and the project type of your repository can help with troubleshooting.

@MiaoTian-MSFT Thanks, I updated the question.

Hi @matt, may I know if adding the file to gitignore  can resolve the issue?

Add the file to ‘.gitignore’ file, so it’s not tracked

According to your update, the file is always the same file name/ext each time.
In this case, adding the file to .gitignore is a good solution so that Git doesn't track the file and changes to it don't appear in the list of changes to commit. You can add the path dist/yourfilename.extension to .gitignore file and commit the .gitignore file to your repository.

In this scenario, would adding the file path to gitignore cause any merge issues?

This will not cause any merge problems because .gitignore only affects untracked files, not files that are already tracked by Git. Since the file does not exist in the remote repository, there should be no conflicts when merging.
